# TCP Bank Application Freezes After Login: Seeking Solutions for Unresponsive Options (1-5)

Tags: java, database, sockets, tcp, io

So, I've been working on this TCP Bank Application. The trouble starts right after successfully logging in. Once I'm in, the app gives me these options (1-5), but when I try to update the password (option 5), everything just freezes up. It's like the app gets stuck and becomes totally unresponsive.

I've checked the code, and it seems that the freezing occurs when I'm trying lodge money. There's this weird "EOFException" that shows up at line 140 in the Client class, mentioning a problem with the ObjectInputStream.

I'm pretty sure the freezing is linked to how the client and server communicate during the lodgement  process. I've looked into both sides of the code, but I can't quite figure out what's causing this freeze. Adding to that, I've tried some error handling and logging, but I'm still stuck.

Any help or ideas on how to get past this freezing issue after login would be a huge help. Thanks a bunch!

> So, after logging into my TCP Bank Application, I wanted to update my password (that's option 1). But instead of smoothly changing the password, the whole thing just freezes up. I expected the lodgement to work seamlessly, but instead, the app becomes unresponsive.
>
> I've dug into the code, checked the communication between the client and server during the password update, and even added some error handling and logging to track what's going on. However, despite all that, the freezing still happens every time I click 1

> It's quite puzzling, and I'm a bit stuck here. Any insights or guidance to resolve this freezing problem post-login would be really appreciated! Thanks a bunch for any help you can provide.

> Here's what I tried

> Client

```
package TCP;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8888;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            boolean loggedIn = false;
            String userId = ""; // Store logged-in user ID

            while (true) {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome! Choose an option:");
                    System.out.println("1. Register an account");
                    System.out.println("2. Login");

                    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline

                    if (choice == 1) {
                        // Registration
                        System.out.print("Enter PPSN: ");
                        String id = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                        String name = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Email: ");
                        String email = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
                        String password = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Address: ");
                        String address = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Balance: ");
                        String balance = scanner.nextLine();

                        // Send registration data to server
                        out.writeObject("REGISTER");
                        out.writeObject(id);
                        out.writeObject(name);
                        out.writeObject(email);
                        out.writeObject(password);
                        out.writeObject(address);
                        out.writeObject(balance);

                        String response = (String) in.readObject();
                        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
                    } else if (choice == 2) {
                        // Login
                        System.out.print("Enter PPSN: ");
                        String id = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
                        String password = scanner.nextLine();

                        // Send login data to server
                        out.writeObject("LOGIN");
                        out.writeObject(id);
                        out.writeObject(password);

                        String response = (String) in.readObject();
                        if (response.equals("LOGIN_SUCCESS")) {
                            loggedIn = true;
                            System.out.println("Login successful!");
                            userId = id;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Login failed. Try again.");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Logged in! Options:");
                    System.out.println("1. Lodge money to the user account.");
                    System.out.println("2. Retrieve all registered users listing.");
                    System.out.println("3. Transfer money to another account.");
                    System.out.println("4. View all transactions on your bank account.");
                    System.out.println("5. Update your password.");
                    System.out.println("0. Log out.");

                    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline

                    switch (choice) {
                        // Inside the client while loop, under case 1 (Lodge money)
                        case 1:
                            // Lodge money
                            out.writeObject("GET_BALANCE");
                            out.writeObject(userId); // Send the user's ID to the server

                            double currentBalance = in.readDouble();
                            System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + currentBalance);

                            System.out.print("Enter the amount to lodge: ");
                            double amountToLodge = scanner.nextDouble();
                            scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline

                            // Send the request to lodge money to the server
                            out.writeObject("LODGE_MONEY");
                            out.writeDouble(amountToLodge);

                            // Read the updated balance from the server
                            double updatedBalance = in.readDouble();
                            System.out.println("Updated balance: " + updatedBalance);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            // Retrieve all registered users listing
                            // Implement functionality to retrieve and display all registered users
                            // Example:
                            out.writeObject("RETRIEVE_USERS");
                            // Receive and display the user listing from the server
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // Transfer money to another account
                            // Implement functionality to transfer money to another account
                            // Example:
                            // Collect recipient details (email, PPS number, etc.)
                            // Send details to the server for the transfer process
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            // View all transactions
                            // Implement functionality to view all transactions on the bank account
                            // Example:
                            out.writeObject("VIEW_TRANSACTIONS");
                            // Receive and display the transactions from the server
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            // Update password
                            // Implement functionality to update the user's password
                            // Example:
                            System.out.print("Enter new password: ");
                            String newPassword = scanner.nextLine();
                            out.writeObject("UPDATE_PASSWORD");
                            out.writeObject(newPassword);
                            String updateResponse = (String) in.readObject();
                            System.out.println("Server: " + updateResponse);
                            break;
                        case 0: // Option to exit or log out
                            System.out.println("Logged out...");
                            out.writeObject("LOGOUT"); // Inform server about logout
                            loggedIn = false; // Reset logged-in state
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please choose a valid option.");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package TCP;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Server {
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8888;
    private static HashMap<String, String[]> accounts = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashSet<String> emailSet = new HashSet<>();
    private static HashSet<String> idSet = new HashSet<>();
    private static HashMap<Socket, String> loggedInUsers = new HashMap<>();
    private static final String DATABASE_FILE = "TCP/database.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadAccounts();
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server started. Listening on port " + SERVER_PORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected: " + clientSocket);

                new Thread(() -> handleClient(clientSocket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void handleClient(Socket clientSocket) {
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;

        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            while (true) {
                String option = (String) in.readObject();
                if (option.equals("REGISTER")) {
                    String id = (String) in.readObject();
                    String name = (String) in.readObject();
                    String email = (String) in.readObject();
                    String password = (String) in.readObject();
                    String address = (String) in.readObject();
                    String balance = (String) in.readObject();

                    if (accounts.containsKey(id)) {
                        out.writeObject("DUPLICATE_ID");
                    } else if (checkDuplicateEmail(email)) {
                        out.writeObject("DUPLICATE_EMAIL");
                    } else {
                        String[] userDetails = {name, email, password, address, balance};
                        accounts.put(id, userDetails);
                        out.writeObject("Registration successful!");
                        saveAccounts();
                    }
                } else if (option.equals("LOGIN")) {
                    String id = (String) in.readObject();
                    String password = (String) in.readObject();
                
                    if (accounts.containsKey(id) && accounts.get(id)[2].equals(password)) {
                        loggedInUsers.put(clientSocket, id);
                        out.writeObject("LOGIN_SUCCESS");
                    } else {
                        out.writeObject("LOGIN_FAILURE");
                    }
                } else if (option.equals("GET_BALANCE")) {
                    String userId = (String) in.readObject();
                    double balance = 0.0;
                    
                    if (accounts.containsKey(userId)) {
                        String[] userDetails = accounts.get(userId);
                        balance = Double.parseDouble(userDetails[userDetails.length - 1]);
                    }
                    
                    out.writeDouble(balance);
                } else if (option.equals("LODGE_MONEY")) {
                    try {
                        String userId = loggedInUsers.get(clientSocket);
                        double amountToLodge = in.readDouble();
                
                        if (userId != null && accounts.containsKey(userId)) {
                            String[] userDetails = accounts.get(userId);
                            double currentBalance = Double.parseDouble(userDetails[userDetails.length - 1]);
                            double updatedBalance = currentBalance + amountToLodge;
                            userDetails[userDetails.length - 1] = String.valueOf(updatedBalance);
                            accounts.put(userId, userDetails);
                            out.writeDouble(updatedBalance);
                        } else {
                            out.writeDouble(-1.0);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkDuplicateEmail(String email) {
        for (String[] userDetails : accounts.values()) {
            if (userDetails[1].equals(email)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void loadAccounts() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATABASE_FILE))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] userInfo = line.split(",");
                String userId = userInfo[0];
                String[] userDetails = new String[userInfo.length - 1];
                System.arraycopy(userInfo, 1, userDetails, 0, userDetails.length);
                accounts.put(userId, userDetails);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void saveAccounts() {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(DATABASE_FILE))) {
            for (String userId : accounts.keySet()) {
                String[] userDetails = accounts.get(userId);
                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(userId);
                for (String detail : userDetails) {
                    line.append(",").append(detail);
                }
                bw.write(line.toString());
                bw.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no handling of option 5 at the server side. Something like:

```
else if (option.equals("UPDATE_PASSWORD")) {
    ...
}
```

... is missing.

So when selecting option 5 from client, the steps are:

1. The client sends `"UPDATE_PASSWORD"` to server.
2. The server reads it as the next `option`.
3. There is no handling of such string for `option` so according to the code the server goes to the next loop waiting for the next `option`.
4. The client then sends the new password (which most likely is not equal to any option).
5. The client password at the server side is read into the `option` variable. The password is unlikely to be any of the predefined string options, so the server ignores it and goes to the next loop and *waits* for the next `option`.
6. At this point the client is already *waiting* for the server's response at:

   ```
   String updateResponse = (String) in.readObject();
   ```

So now both sides are waiting each other for input. Since input and output are handled by a single `Thread` at client side then it is not going to send anything. Same for server side (on a per-connection basis). As such, they are both blocked.

To prevent this, make sure you handle the options in the same way at both sides.

Also, in the coded provided, there is state at the client side (the `loggedIn` and user id variables) which is not at the server side. So how will the server know in which state each client is (so as to properly handle each state)? For example what if some client sends the `"LODGE_MONEY"` command before logging in? What if some client sends `"REGISTER"` command twice? What if a logged in client sends `"LODGE_MONEY"` command for a different user id than the one used for logging in? Etc... It is important to note that the state of the connection should be kept at least on server side.